# Are solar panels ever used to remove energy?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, cooling

Solar panels convert energy from the sun into electrical energy. Following the first law of thermodynamics, this means they remove some of the solar energy that would otherwise most likely be absorbed as heat or reflected.

Generally the former is the primary, intended effect, since the electrical energy can easily be transported elsewhere, stored, converted to various other types, etc.

However, I can imagine they could also be used for the latter effect, i.e. to remove some (potential) heat from where you don't want it, to electrically transport it to some place where you freely can dump it, and without reflecting it elsewhere, where it may also be undesired.

Is that practical? Are there examples where they are mainly or partially applied for this purpose? Or are there always better alternative solutions for that particular problem?

Comment: You don't need a solar panel for that. There are cheaper ways of reflecting the sunlight.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes of course, that's why I explicitly specified target problems where reflecting the light is not desired either. But perhaps such problems simply don't exist, since you could at least always retro-reflect it right back at the sun.

Comment: Well, for "partial" you can think of the Tesla's "Solar roof" thing. It is both producing electricity, and also would somewhat isolate the roof from overheating by the sunlight.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this applies to all solar panels mounted on roofs, even if they are not integral roofing materials in addition to being solar panels.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, of course. It's a bit easier to make the point about solar roof, as it is tightly covering the whole house.

Comment: I would say no, since even with a 30% efficient solar panel, the lion's share of the energy is either being reflected or absorbed.  If you have some sort of treatment that eliminates or reduces the reflection part, you'll need a cooling system to prevent re-radiation and at that point it's probably more economically feasible to just use a very absorptive surface (Vantablack, maybe?) and bump up your cooling capacity by 30%.

Comment: Most solar panels are designed to be highly absorbing relative to normal materials so it isn't necessarily true that remove any net energy.  They're frequently going to increase absorption by more than the energy they transmit away as heat.

Comment: An SP might be 20% efficient so, how can that make it a useful heatsink? Does it reflect back the 80% or does it just heat up with the 80% making it virtually useless in the proposed application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I can imagine they could also be used for the latter effect, i.e. to remove (or wick away, so to speak) some heat without reflecting it elsewhere, where it may also be undesired.

Yes, solar panels do absorb radiation as heat, but I'm going to say that it *usually* isn't practical to use them primarily for that purpose. There may be some niche cases where they serve a dual purpose to keep something cool **and** generate electricity, but most applications where cooling without reflection is important will use different materials with better absorption properties that are also probably cheaper.

For example, satellites will typically be covered in all sorts of reflective blanketing that is used for thermal insulation. Here's some people putting this blanketing on the James Webb Space Telescope (source is Wikipedia).

[image]

But this can be a problem for the cameras/sensors/telescopes on the satellite and cause [straylight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_light) effects. This is why some places on a satellite may have black paint. You may think it would be efficient to kill two birds with one stone and replace that black paint with solar panels that prevent straylight **and** generate electricity, but you have two problems.

1. Black paint (at least the stuff they use on satellites) is much better at absorbing light than solar panels which are still somewhat reflective.
2. Solar panels are more expensive and weigh more than paint. Satellite solar panels are *really* expensive, and every gram counts when you have to pay to throw something 400+ km into the air, so solar panels on a satellite are optimized to be in places where they will see maximum sunlight which leads to maximum efficiency. The places where you want to keep straylight away from the satellite, you want to keep out of the sun as much as possible because it's really hard to transfer that heat away from the satellite.

I recognize this is only one application example, but it highlights some points as to why it's probably not practical to use solar panels as a radiation heat sink in most applications. Also as a side note, heating of solar panels is usually a big undesirable because it makes them less efficient and reduces their lifetime.

Comment: Note that MLI blankets are also used to keep heat in - to prevent parts of the satellite from becoming too cold, which is a real possibility for parts of the spacecraft that face deep space.

Comment: @SteveSh good point, I’ve generalized that part of the answer to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly common where I live to see solar panels set up over parking lots.

This not only produces electrical energy, it also shades the cars parked there, reducing their need to run air conditioning when they are driven away.

Economically, the benefit of shading the cars is entirely incidental, (the fact that parking lots are large, easily accessible, and relatively uncluttered being more important from an engineering and economics perspective) but it is a pleasant side effect of placing the solar cells over the parking lot.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate electricity using solar panels and use it for various appliances on earth, virtually all of it is converted to heat eventually! Only a tiny fraction escapes back to space, e.g. as visible light from road lamps or radio broadcast energy.

Therefore, solar panels actually bind more thermal energy on earth than most natural surface, even than those with rather low albedo (such as ocean or forests).

I believe, that in a few 100 years, when the current climate crisis has been tackled with a strong move towards solar energy generation, there will be the next global warming crisis on the horizon, because energy generation and consumption as a whole will have likely strongly increased and will warm the planet regardless, even without excess CO2 in the atmosphere.

I think the best albedo you can achieve with solar panels is something like 40%. First, the electricity generation is only maybe 40-50% efficient (using exotic cells) and then you lose a bit more in converting that electricity into an energy beam that you point towards outer space. Clouds or snow are much better than this, as are some artificial surfaces (see other answers).

Comment: The hypothetical goal would not be to prevent the conversion to heat entirely, just to electrically transport it from where you don't want it to some place where you can dump it. That said, the note that most energy ends up as heat somewhere nearby is a good thing to keep in mind in general.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen solar panels used for a dual use application like you mentioned.

On spacecraft other means are used to remove heat from the spacecraft than the solar panels.  These involve use of special coatings to aid in emissivity  (radiation) and even dedicated thermal radiators (a lot like solar panels, only designed to radiate heat into deep space).

One reason for the different equipment is that solar panels need to oriented broadside to the sun, in order to maximize the amount of solar energy captured and thus converted to electricity.  This is NOT how you want a thermal radiator oriented, which wants to be pointed to deep space, away from the sun and away from the earth.